# Need to send arraylist to webservice from client and return modified arraylist

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey

I have started out by creating a basic webservice with a @GET method shown below.

```
package com.webservice.eoin;

import java.awt.PageAttributes.MediaType;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;



@Path("/webservice")

public class Web_service {
@PUT
@Path("/getname")
@Produces("text/plain")

  public String getname()
  {
return "hello!!!";
  }




}
```

this works fine when I run it. I have all the jar files and web.xml file setup etc. What i want to do next is create a client that sends an arraylist of strings to the webservice and returns a modified version of the arraylist to the client. My question is first of all how do you set up the client? and how do I run it so it sends this arraylist to the server. Ive read a lot of tutorials but Iam finding some of them hard to follow. Im new to making webservices in Java. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I am sorry I copied a lot of code from the project I am working on currently, but it would be cumbersome otherwise. Please excuse if I have typos or compile errors. Also, beware that you need an external library for this.

The client:

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.GenericType;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.client.apache.ApacheHttpClient;
import com.sun.jersey.client.apache.config.ApacheHttpClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.client.apache.config.DefaultApacheHttpClientConfig;

public Client {

    private final URI fServerURI;
    private final ApacheHttpClient fClient;
    private final MediaType fMediaType= MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE;

    public Client() {
            final String apiEndpoint= "...";
            final DefaultApacheHttpClientConfig clientConfig;
            fServerURI= UriBuilder.fromUri(apiEndpoint).build();
            clientConfig= new DefaultApacheHttpClientConfig();
            clientConfig.getProperties().put(ApacheHttpClientConfig.PROPERTY_HANDLE_COOKIES, true);
            fClient= ApacheHttpClient.create(clientConfig);
    }

    private <T> T call(WebResource resource, RequestType requestType, Object requestEntity, GenericType<T> acceptType, String taskMessage) {
            return acceptCall(resource, requestType, acceptType, requestEntity);
    }

    private <T> T acceptCall(WebResource resource, RequestType requestType, GenericType<T> acceptType, Object requestEntity) {
           switch (requestType) {
           case POST:
                return resource.accept(fMediaType).post(acceptType, requestEntity);
           case PUT:
                return resource.accept(fMediaType).put(acceptType, requestEntity);
           case DELETE:
                resource.accept(fMediaType).delete();
                return null;
           default:
                return resource.accept(fMediaType).get(acceptType);
    }

    public MyArrayList sendArrayList(MyArrayList list) {
           WebResource resource= createResource();
           resource= resource.path("webservice").path("sendarraylist");
           resource= resource.queryParam("arraylist", list);
           return call(resource, RequestType.POST, null, new GenericType<MyArrayList>() {
    }, "Send my array list");
    }

    public static void main(String ... args) {
           Client c= new Client();
           MyArrayList result= c.sendArrayList(new MyArrayList(/*whatevs goes inside*/));
    }
 }
```

In the server you need something like:

```
    @POST
    @Path("/sendarraylist")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    MyArrayList modifyList(@QueryParam("arraylist") MyArrayList list) {
        //do stuff
    }
```

The last thing that is left is to create `MyArrayList` class according JAXB rules (see this example: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JAXB/article.html)

Comment: Also I was just wondering should I run a client in a seperate application?